# How to handle multiple pages with playwright-python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, playwright, playwright-python

How to listen for new pages with [playwright-python](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-python)?

In JavaScript it will be documented as:

```
const playwright = require("playwright");

(async () => {
  const browser = await playwright.chromium.launch();
  const context = await browser.newContext();
  const page = await context.newPage();
  context.on("page", async newPage => {
    console.log("newPage", await newPage.title())
  })

  // emulate some opening in a new tab or popup
  await page.evaluate(() => window.open('https://google.com', '_blank'))
  // Keep in mind to have some blocking action there so that the browser won't be closed. In this case we are just waiting 2 seconds.
  await page.waitForTimeout(2000)
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Becomes in Python

```
from playwright import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(
        headless=False,
        executablePath='C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'
    )
    context = browser.newContext()
    page = context.newPage()

'''
how to do in Python?
  context.on("page", async newPage => {
    console.log("newPage", await newPage.title())
  })

  // emulate some opening in a new tab or popup
  await page.evaluate(() => window.open('https://google.com', '_blank'))
'''

    page.waitForTimeout(2000)
    browser.close()
```

Comment: Would this help https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-python/blob/f7c2dc1b51461ad9130a87aea6578124b603fac9/tests/async/test_browsercontext.py#L707?

Comment: Thank. below my  solution.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to handle new page without event listener (i.e. new tab open by link click), you can try this code:

```
    from playwright import sync_playwright

    with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser = p.chromium.launch()
        context = browser.newContext()
        page = context.newPage()
        page.goto('<site url>')
        with context.expect_page() as tab:
            page.click('.newTabByLink')
        # do some steps
        ...
        tab.close()
        
        browser.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you to @hardkoded
Here's the solution:

```
from playwright import sync_playwright

def newPage(page):
   print("newPage() page title:", page.title())

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(
        headless=False,
        executablePath='C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'
    )
    context = browser.newContext()
    page = context.newPage()

    context.on("page", lambda page: newPage(page))

    page.evaluate('''() => {
        window.open('https://google.com', '_blank')
    }''')
       
    page.waitForTimeout(2000)
    browser.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the right answer, playwright-python team should update their doc for multiple pages handle scenarios. It's too hard to get the answer.

Here's the solution:

```py
with context.expect_page() as new_page:
    page.click("#multi")

pages = new_page.value.context.pages
for new_page in pages:
    new_page.wait_for_load_state()
    logging.info(new_page.title())
```

**Reference:**

https://playwright.dev/python/docs/pages

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DyHQ3G442jY&list=PL699Xf-_ilW7EyC6lMuU4jelKemmS6KgD&index=12